# Google reCAPTCHA блокирует работу сайта на ПК

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс, recaptcha, xss

На сайте появился странный баг: при посещении [unisem.ru](https://unisem.ru) открывается "капча гугловская", которая на самом деле таковой не является. XSS что-ли.
Искал через grep, прогнал через айболит, ничего не могу найти. Если кто-то сталкивался, помогите пж.
Сайт на битриксе, лежит на VDS
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня нет такого, проверяйте свой браузер на наличие вредоносных расширений

Comment: Оплатите работу специалиста на устранение проблемы, это похоже на примитивный взлом.

Comment: Ребята подскажите решение с такой же проблемой столкнулся, самостоятельные поиски ничего не дали

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Было выявлено, что на появление псевдокаптчи влияет кэш сайта. После чистки кеша проблема исчезает, но появляется снова через 10-15 минут. Пока источник появления вредоносного скрипта не найден.

Временное решение - периодическая чистка всего кеша в админке: `/bitrix/admin/cache.php?lang=ru&tabControl_active_tab=fedit2`.

Чтобы не делать это руками, можно в скрипте `/bitrix/modules/main/admin/cache.php` в функцию `StartClearCache()` добавить:

```
setTimeout(StartClearCache, 600000);
```

Которая будет перезапускать чистку через 10 минут. Админку не закрывать.

После решения проблемы не забыть вернуть скрипт в исходное состояние.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не нашли какое-то решение?